# How to use the OWB repository assistant using command line

Tags: oracle, repository, builder, assistant, warehouse

We need to migrate our OWB repository to a new one running on 11.2. This will eventually be converted to ODI but as a 1st step we need to do this migration.

I've been following the notes in
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e17130/migrate.htm#WBINS07100

But we won't have access to a GUI for the repository assistant and need to run this from the command line.

Anybody have suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the OWB repository assistant in command line from the following location.

Go to the following location and run the command

In AIX or LINUX:

```
$OWB_HOME/owb/bin/unix/
./reposinst.sh
```

In windows:

```
$OWB_HOME/owb/bin/unix/reposinst.cmd
```